# iOS Realtime Audio I/O

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, real-time, recording

new to iOS development, i have managed to create a basic app that can record audio through the iPhone main mic / headset mic, then replay that audio when the play button is pressed.

what i need is to simultaneously play the currently recording audio, rather than recording to a file, then playing back post recording.
so basically, create a realtime audio loop between (for example) the headset mic, and earphones.

is it possible to achieve this?

if so, could someone please help point me in the right direction to implement this functionality. required frameworks and any code snippets woud be greatly appreciated.

many many thanks in

Comment: If I were you I would go with some framework. It takes weeks to learn things like DSP Kernel subclassing and Core Audio overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes what you seek to do is very much possible.  Take a look at 
[AurioTouch](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/aurioTouch2.0-Swift)

Comment: thank you for the reply.
i have been looking at AurioTouch previously. yet am finding it very difficult to isolate the methods within the program that are responsible for the actions i am after. is there anywhere on the web that walks through the aurio touch example?